# how do universal turing machines actually work

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, turing-machines

a TM has states and a tape, and a set of symbols that can get put on the tape. when it 'reads' a symbol on the tape, it's current 'state' tells it what to do next; write a new symbol, where to move next, and what state to transition to.

i do not understand how 'reading' one set of symbols out of the limited set the UTM can already read, can lead it to 'invent' new states and new symbols of potentially unlimited scope.

I get in theory, humans can use symbols to represent other more complex symbols or instructions, e.g. i can represent 'train' by the letter 't' or i can use '1111' to represent 17' - but how can a UTM, upon reading a set of familar symbols, know that it needs to use that set of symbols to stand in for a set of states it does not already have in its library?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, UTM's work just the same way as actual, physical computers -- they store their instructions in memory.

Therefore it's easiest to conceptualize a UTM with two tapes: one (read-only) that holds the description of the TM to be simulated (in some standardized format), and one that holds the data to be manipulated. The rules of the universal TM says that the tapeheads should work according to the rules of the input TM.

Of course, everything that can be done with two tapes can be achieved with one as well, but single-tape UTM's have to jump between code and data constantly, thus spending longer time.